# Conocer el tamaño del navegador en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Quisiera cambiar el atributo Width de un TextBox en ASP.NET según el tamaño del navegador, pero no sé cómo obtener el ancho del navegador en C#. ¿Alguna ayuda?

Me gustaría hacer algo así:

```
if (tamañoNavegador > ciertaCantidad)
    TexBox.Width = 50%;
else
    TextBox.Width = 100%;
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dicha operación tiene que ver con el lado del cliente  ,  no es necesario manejarlo desde el lado del servidor. Se puede usar javascript o css3 empleando  [Media Querys](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries)

Ejemplo en Javascript

```
var width = $(window).width(); 
var height = $(window).height();
```

Ejemplo css3 Media Querys , cuando la ventana del navegador es menor a 500px , lo que hará es asignar un ancho de `100px` a todos los input de tipo text

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    input[type="text"]{
        width:100px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Igual es una pregunta estúpida, pero no soy muy ducho con javascript... ¿Puedo alterar código ASP desde javascript? Un saludo!

Comment: Puedes modificar cuestiones del lado del cliente , diseño, validaciones, funcionalidad y algunas cosas más. aunque para diseño es mejor emplear css3 o algún framework como Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas sencillo es que utilices algún framework web, que te permita hacer paginas web responsive, Te recomiendo bootstrapp, es muy facil y sencillo de utilizar, ya que a tu form HTML, le puedes aplicar los estilos css y decirle cuantas columnas va a tener de ancho, con lo cual no buscarias pixeles o medidas, podrias redimensionar tus componentes en base a las columnas.

Y por si fuera poco hay un manual en español.

http://librosweb.es/libro/bootstrap_3/

Answer (score 0):

El ancho lo Podes obtener con

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
```